# Obtaining babel-french automatic spaces before punctuation when using pandoc

Tags: languages, pandoc, french

I'm trying to get `pandoc` (which converts Markdown to PDF using LaTeX) to produce PDFs which respect French typesetting rules concerning [non-breakable spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

[The suggestions here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119132/changing-language-settings-used-by-pandoc-for-generated-output-pandoc-templat) do not seem to work, e.g. `pandoc test.md -V lang:fr-FR -o test.pdf` or `pandoc test.md -M lang:fr-FR -o test.pdf`.

What am I missing? I'm using `pandoc` 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. The goal is to start with a Markdown file `text.md` such as `a;b` and to obtain in output a PDF file showing `a ;b` where the space is non-breakable.

Comment: I really do thing that this question is off-topic and not connected to (La)TeX. On the other hand `a\ b` creates tilde during conversion to LaTeX or docx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `pandoc` template for LaTeX output appears to force `shorthands=off` in the `babel` options. Indeed, after running `pandoc -D latex >default.latex`, you should see:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode=true}{hyperref} % options for packages loaded elsewhere

(...)

$if(lang)$
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[shorthands=off,$for(babel-otherlangs)$$babel-otherlangs$,$endfor$main=$babel-lang$]{babel}
$if(babel-newcommands)$
  $babel-newcommands$
$endif$
\else

(...)

\end{document}
```

This `shorthands=off` option kills the feature you want. You can fix this the following way:

1. Get the default LaTeX template in a file called `mytemplate.latex`:

   ```
   pandoc -D latex >mytemplate.latex
   ```
2. In `mytemplate.latex`, use your favorite text editor to remove the `shorthands=off` option passed to `babel`.
3. Compile with:

   ```latex
   pandoc -f markdown -t latex -M lang:fr-FR --template=mytemplate -o test.pdf test.md
   ```

This should work if `mytemplate.latex` is either in the current directory or in `~/.pandoc/templates`.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much!

Comment: I ran into problems with `--listings`. I wanted to display inline `\`:Joueur\`` which renders in PDF as `Joueur:` (not sure why, but the shortcuts are messing it up). I was able to work around this by turning it off around the inline listing by doing `\shorthandoff{:}\`:Joueur\`\shorthandon{:}` inside the markdown.