# Lines are not wrapping on thinspace, `\,`, zero-width space (ZWSP), or other unicode space characters

Tags: spacing, symbols, fontspec, unicode, utf8

Asian languages frequently do not use spaces, yet still have "words" which must be broken and wrapped at the right places.  I am working with such a language, and actually want to put in a "thin space" between those words, as opposed to having no space at all as is traditional.  However, none of the spaces appear to be recognized by XeLaTeX as a suitable break point for word wrapping, and the lines simply end up extending off the page.

In the image below, I mixed several styles, beginning with actual spaces (wraps normally), and then going to the `\,` thin space (equiv. to U+2009), followed by the 'Four-Per-Em Space' unicode character (U+2005): about ten verses for each.  The result is obvious.

[image: Image showing spaced/wrapped versus thin-spaced/non-wrapped lines]

Actual TeX code for this follows:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,13pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}     
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{lettrine}   
\usepackage{eso-pic}    
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{fontspec}   

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Phetsarath OT}  %Angsana New
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Phetsarath OT}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Phetsarath OT}

\makeatletter

% plan b make multicol add two rules
\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}
\def\LR@column@boxes{%
     \process@cols\mult@gfirstbox{%
       \ifdim\dp\count@>\dimen\tw@
         \global\dimen\tw@\dp\count@ \fi
       \mc@col@status@write
       \box\count@
       \kern2pt %
       {\columnseprulecolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule}%
       \hss
       {\columnseprulecolor\vrule \@width\columnseprule}%
       \kern2pt}%
     \ifdim\dp\mult@rightbox>\dimen\tw@
       \global\dimen\tw@\dp\mult@rightbox \fi
     \mc@lastcol@status@write
     \box\mult@rightbox
}
\LRmulticolcolumns

\makeatother

\settypeblocksize{9.4in}{6.1in}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{0.85}
\checkandfixthelayout

\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}% Copy plain page syle to chapter page style
\makeoddhead{chapter}% Adjust odd header for chapter page style
  {\leftmark}% Left odd header
  {\thepage}% Center odd header
  {\rightmark}% Right odd header
\makeevenhead{chapter}% Adjust odd header for chapter page style
  {\leftmark}% Left odd header
  {\thepage}% Center odd header
  {\rightmark}% Right odd header
\makepagestyle{hurried}% Create hurried page style
\makeevenhead{hurried}% Adjust even header for hurried page style
  {\rightmark}% Left even header
  {\thepage}% Center even header
  {\leftmark}% Right even header
\makeoddhead{hurried}% Adjust odd header for hurried page style
  {\rightmark}% Left odd header
  {\thepage}% Center odd header
  {\leftmark}% Right odd header
\makeheadrule{hurried}{\textwidth}{.4pt}% Header rule width/thickness for hurried page style
\makefootrule{hurried}{\textwidth}{.4pt}{\footruleskip}% Footer rule width/thickness/skip for hurried page style

\pagestyle{hurried}% Set page style to hurried

\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx,lipsum}    
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{ເນື້ອໃນ}

% set up ordinary footnotes
\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width \textwidth \kern 2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textit{\arabic{footnote}}}

% code to create chapters, verses, and cross references
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \crossref_int
\int_new:N \vs_int
\tl_new:N \crossref_tl

% insert a cross reference
\NewDocumentCommand {\crossref} {m}
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT { \crossref_int } > { 25 }
      {
        \int_set:Nn \crossref_int { 0 }
      }
    \int_incr:N \crossref_int
% PROVIDES SUPERSCRIPTS FOR REFERENCES
%    \textsuperscript{ \emph { \int_to_alph:n { \crossref_int } } }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \crossref_tl
      {
        \tl_gput_right:Nn \emph { \crossref_tl { ~ } }
      }
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \crossref_tl
      {
% PROVIDES SUPERSCRIPTS FOR REFERENCES
%        \exp_not:N \textsuperscript
%          {
%            \exp_not:N \emph { \int_to_alph:n { \crossref_int } }
%          }
        \, #1
      }
  }

%Sample output
% insert chapter marker
\NewDocumentCommand {\ch} {m}
  {
    \int_gset:Nn \vs_int {1}
    \lettrine [findent=0.5em,nindent=0em] { #1 } {}
  }

% output cross references from previous verse and insert verse marker
\NewDocumentCommand {\vs} {m}
  {
    \tl_if_empty:NF \crossref_tl
      {
        \sidebar
          {
            \textbf { \int_use:N \vs_int } \, \tl_use:N \crossref_tl
          }
      }
    \int_gset:Nn \vs_int { #1 }
    \tl_gclear:N \crossref_tl
    %\textsuperscript { #1 \, }
    %\textbf { #1 \, }
    \par\textbf{\large{\textsuperscript{#1 \, }}}
  }

% output any remaining cross references
\AtEndDocument
  {
    \tl_if_empty:NF \crossref_tl
      {
        \sidebar
          {
            \textbf { \int_use:N \vs_int } \, \tl_use:N \crossref_tl
          }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


% set up centre column location and size
\setlength\columnsep{2.2cm}     %ORIGINAL: {2.5cm}
\setlength{\sidebarhsep}{\dimexpr -0.5\textwidth - 0.5\columnsep + 2mm}
\setlength{\sidebarwidth}{\dimexpr \columnsep - 4mm}
\sidebarmargin{left}        % ADDED THIS LINE
\renewcommand{\sidebarfont}{\footnotesize\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\sidebarform}{\raggedright\hangindent 1mm}
\setlength{\sidebarvsep}{0ex}
\setsidebarheight{\dimexpr \textheight - 1ex}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage

\begin{multicols}{2}


\begingroup
\begin{minipage}{.25in}{\hspace{20pt}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{\ch{1}} \par}\end{minipage}\markboth{ປະຖົມມະການ 1}{ປະຖົມມະການ 1}\crossref{ຢຮ 1:1-2; ຮຣ 1:10; ພສສ 8:3; ອຊຢ 44:24; ກຈກ 17:24; ພນມ 4:11}
ໃນ ເລີ່ມຕົ້ນ ນັ້ນ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ນິລະມິດ ສ້າງ ຟ້າສະຫວັນ ແລະ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ.
\vs{2}
\crossref{ຢມຢ 4:23; ພສສ 33:6; ອຊຢ 40:13-14}
ແລະ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ນັ້ນ ກໍ ປາສະຈາກ ຮູບຮ່າງ ແລະ ຫວ່າງເປົ່າ; ຄວາມມືດ ຢູ່ ເທິງ ໜ້າ ຄວາມເລິກ ແລະ ພຣະວິນຍານ ຂອງ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ເຄື່ອນໄຫວ ເທິງ ໜ້ານໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ.
\vs{3}
\crossref{ພສສ 33:9; 2 ກຣທ 4:6}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ຈົ່ງ ໃຫ້ ມີ ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ”: ແລະ ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ ກໍ ເກີດຂຶ້ນ.
\vs{4}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເຫັນ ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ ວ່າ ດີ: ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ແຍກ ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ ອອກຈາກ ຄວາມມືດ.
\vs{5}
\crossref{ພສສ 74:16}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເອີ້ນ ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ ວ່າ “ກາງເວັນ,” ແລະ ພຣະອົງ ຊົງ ເອີ້ນ ຄວາມມືດ ວ່າ “ກາງຄືນ.” ຕອນແລງ ແລະ ຕອນເຊົ້າ ເປັນ ມື້ ທີ ໜຶ່ງ.
\vs{6}
\crossref{ໂຢບ 37:18; ຢມຢ 10:12}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ຈົ່ງ ໃຫ້ ມີ ພື້ນອາກາດ ໃນ ລະຫວ່າງ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ ແລະ ຈົ່ງ ໃຫ້ ມັນ ແຍກ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ ອອກຈາກ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ.”
\vs{7}
\crossref{ສພສ 8:28; ພສສ 148:4}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ສ້າງ ພື້ນອາກາດ ແລະ ຊົງ ແຍກ ລະຫວ່າງ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ ເຊິ່ງ ຢູ່ ໃຕ້ ພື້ນອາກາດ ແລະ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ ເຊິ່ງ ຢູ່ ເໜືອ ພື້ນອາກາດ: ແລະ ເປັນ ດັ່ງນັ້ນ.
\vs{8}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເອີ້ນ ພື້ນອາກາດ ວ່າ,  “ຟ້າສະຫວັນ.” ຕອນແລງ ແລະ ຕອນເຊົ້າ ເປັນ ມື້ ທີ ສອງ.
\vs{9}
\crossref{ໂຢບ 26:10; ສພສ 8:29; ຢມຢ 5:22; 2 ປຕ 3:5}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ຈົ່ງ ໃຫ້ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ ທີ່ ຢູ່ ໃຕ້ ຟ້າສະຫວັນ ຮວບຮວມ ເຂົ້າ ຢູ່ ບ່ອນ ດຽວກັນ ແລະ ຈົ່ງ ໃຫ້ ພື້ນດິນ ແຫ້ງ ປາກົດ ຂຶ້ນ”: ແລະ ເປັນ ດັ່ງນັ້ນ.
\vs{10}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເອີ້ນ ພື້ນດິນ ແຫ້ງ ວ່າ, “ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ,” ແລະ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ ຮວບຮວມ ເຂົ້າ ຢູ່ ບ່ອນ ດຽວກັນ ເອີ້ນ ວ່າ, “ທະເລ”: ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເຫັນ ວ່າ ດີ.
\vs{11}
\crossref{ຮຣ 6:7; ລກ 6:44}
ແລະ\,ພຣະເຈົ້າ\,ຊົງ\,ກ່າວ\,ວ່າ,\,“ຈົ່ງ\,ໃຫ້\,ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ\,ເກີດ\,ຕົ້ນຫຍ້າ,\,ພືດຜັກ\,ທີ່\,ມີ\,ເມັດພັນ,\,ແລະ\,ຕົ້ນໄມ້\,ທີ່\,ອອກ\,ຜົນ\,ຕາມ\,ຊະນິດ\,ຂອງ\,ມັນ\,ທີ່\,ມີ\,ເມັດພັນ\,ໃນ\,ຜົນ\,ມັນເອງ\,ເທິງ\,ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ”:\,ແລະ\,ເປັນ\,ດັ່ງນັ້ນ.
\vs{12}
ແລະ\,ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ\,ກໍ\,ເກີດ\,ຕົ້ນຫຍ້າ,\,ພືດຜັກ\,ທີ່\,ມີ\,ເມັດພັນ\,ຕາມ\,ຊະນິດ\,ຂອງ\,ມັນ,\,ແລະ\,ຕົ້ນໄມ້\,ທີ່\,ອອກ\,ຜົນ\,ທີ່\,ມີ\,ເມັດພັນ\,ໃນ\,ຜົນ\,ມັນເອງ\,ຕາມ\,ຊະນິດ\,ຂອງ\,ມັນ:\,ແລະ\,ພຣະເຈົ້າ\,ຊົງ\,ເຫັນ\,ວ່າ\,ດີ.
\vs{13}
ຕອນແລງ\,ແລະ\,ຕອນເຊົ້າ\,ເປັນ\,ມື້\,ທີ\,ສາມ.
\vs{14}
ແລະ\,ພຣະເຈົ້າ\,ຊົງ\,ກ່າວວ່າ,\,“ຈົ່ງ\,ໃຫ້\,ມີ\,ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງໆ\,ໃນ\,ພື້ນອາກາດ\,ຟ້າສະຫວັນ\,ເພື່ອ\,ແຍກ\,ກາງເວັນ\,ອອກຈາກ\,ກາງຄືນ\,ແລະ\,ໃຫ້\,ເປັນ\,ສຳລັບ\,ເຄື່ອງໝາຍ,\,ລະດູ,\,ວັນ\,ແລະ\,ປີ.
\vs{15}
ແລະ\,ຈົ່ງ\,ໃຫ້\,ເປັນ\,ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງໆ\,ໃນ\,ພື້ນອາກາດ\,ຟ້າສະຫວັນ\,ເພື່ອ\,ສ່ອງສະຫວ່າງ\,ເທິງ\,ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ”:\,ແລະ\,ເປັນ\,ດັ່ງນັ້ນ.
\vs{16}
\crossref{ພສສ 136:8; ພສສ 8:3; ໂຢບ 38:7}
ແລະ\,ພຣະເຈົ້າ\,ຊົງ\,ສ້າງ\,ສອງ\,ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ\,ໃຫຍ່;\,ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ\,ທີ່\,ໃຫຍ່\,ກວ່າ\,ເພື່ອ\,ຄອບຄອງ\,ກາງເວັນ\,ແລະ\,ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ\,ທີ່\,ນ້ອຍ\,ກວ່າ\,ເພື່ອ\,ຄອບຄອງ\,ກາງຄືນ:\,ພຣະອົງ\,ຊົງ\,ສ້າງ\,ດວງດາວ\,ທັງຫຼາຍ\,ເຊັ່ນກັນ.
\vs{17}
ແລະ\,ພຣະເຈົ້າ\,ຊົງ\,ຕັ້ງ\,ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ\,ເຫຼົ່ານີ້\,ໃນ\,ພື້ນອາກາດ\,ຟ້າສະຫວັນ\,ເພື່ອ\,ສ່ອງສະຫວ່າງ\,ເທິງ\,ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ.
\vs{18}
\crossref{ຢມຢ 31:35}
ແລະ\,ເພື່ອ\,ຄອບຄອງ\,ກາງເວັນ\,ແລະ\,ຄອບຄອງ\,ກາງຄືນ;\,ແລະ\,ເພື່ອ\,ແຍກ\,ຄວາມສະຫວ່າງ\,ອອກຈາກ\,ຄວາມມືດ:\,ແລະ\,ພຣະເຈົ້າ\,ຊົງ\,ເຫັນ\,ວ່າ\,ດີ.
\vs{19}
ຕອນແລງ\,ແລະ\,ຕອນເຊົ້າ\,ເປັນ\,ມື້\,ທີ\,ສີ່.
\vs{20}
ແລະ\,ພຣະເຈົ້າ\,ຊົງ\,ກ່າວ\,ວ່າ,\,“ຈົ່ງ\,ໃຫ້\,ນໍ້າ\,ທັງຫຼາຍ\,ອຸດົມ\,ສົມບູນ\,ໄປ\,ດ້ວຍ\,ສັບພະສິ່ງທີ່ສ້າງຂຶ້ນ\,ທີ່\,ມີ\,ຊີວິດ\,ເຄື່ອນໄຫວ,\,ແລະ\,ໃຫ້\,ສັດປີກ\,ບິນ\,ເໜືອ\,ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ\,ໃນ\,ພື້ນອາກາດ\,ຟ້າສະຫວັນ.”
\vs{21}
\crossref{ພສສ 104:26}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ສ້າງ ປາວານ ໃຫຍ່, ແລະ ບັນດາ ສັບພະສິ່ງທີ່ສ້າງຂຶ້ນ ມີຊີວິດ ທີ່ ເຄື່ອນໄຫວ ເຊິ່ງ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ ໄດ້ ບັງເກີດ ທະວີ ຕາມ ຊະນິດ ຂອງ ມັນ, ແລະ ບັນດາ ສັດບິນ ທີ່ ມີ ປີກ ຕາມ ຊະນິດ ຂອງ ມັນ: ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເຫັນ ວ່າ ດີ.
\vs{22}
\crossref{ປຖກ 8:17}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ອວຍພອນ ສັດ ເຫຼົ່ານັ້ນ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ຈົ່ງ ມີ ລູກ ດົກ ແລະ ທະວີ ຫຼາຍ ຂຶ້ນ, ແລະ ເຕັມ ນໍ້າ ທັງຫຼາຍ ໃນ ທະເລ, ແລະ ຈົ່ງ ໃຫ້ ສັດປີກ ທະວີ ຫຼາຍ ຂຶ້ນ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ.”
\vs{23}
ຕອນແລງ ແລະ ຕອນເຊົ້າ ເປັນ ມື້ ທີ ຫ້າ.
\vs{24}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ຈົ່ງ ໃຫ້ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ເກີດ ສັບພະສິ່ງທີ່ສ້າງຂຶ້ນ ມີຊີວິດ ຕາມ ຊະນິດ ຂອງ ມັນ, ສັດໃຊ້ແຮງງານ, ສັດເລືອຄານ, ແລະ ສັດ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ຕາມ ຊະນິດ ຂອງ ມັນ”: ແລະ ເປັນ ດັ່ງນັ້ນ.
\vs{25}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ສ້າງ ສັດ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ຕາມ ຊະນິດ ຂອງ ມັນ, ແລະ ສັດໃຊ້ແຮງງານ ຕາມ ຊະນິດ ຂອງ ມັນ ແລະ ທຸກໆ ສິ່ງ ທີ່ ເລືອຄານ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ຕາມ ຊະນິດ ຂອງ ມັນ: ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເຫັນ ວ່າ ດີ.
\vs{26}
\crossref{ພສສ 100:3; ປຍຈ 7:29; ອຟຊ 4:24; ຢກບ 3:9; ປຖກ 9:2; ພສສ 8:6}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ຈົ່ງ ໃຫ້ ພວກເຮົາ ສ້າງ ມະນຸດ ຕາມ ແບບ ຮູບ ລັກສະນະ ຂອງ ພວກເຮົາ, ຄ້າຍຄື ພວກເຮົາ: ແລະ ໃຫ້ ພວກເຂົາ ຄອບຄອງ ເໜືອ ປາ ໃນ ທະເລ, ເໜືອ ສັດປີກ ໃນ ອາກາດ, ແລະ ເໜືອ ສັດໃຊ້ແຮງງານ, ແລະ ເໜືອ ທົ່ວ ທັງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ, ແລະ ເໜືອ ບັນດາ ສັດເລືອຄານ ທີ່ ເລືອຄານ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ.”
\vs{27}
\crossref{1 ກຣທ 11:7; ປຖກ 5:2; ມທ 19:4}
ດັ່ງນັ້ນ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ສ້າງ ມະນຸດ ຕາມ ແບບ ຮູບ ລັກສະນະ ຂອງ ພຣະອົງ, ໃນ ຮູບ ລັກສະນະ ຂອງ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ພຣະອົງ ຊົງ ສ້າງ ລາວ; ຊາຍ ແລະ ຍິງ ພຣະອົງ ຊົງ ສ້າງ ພວກເຂົາ.
\vs{28}
\crossref{ປຖກ 9:1,7; ລລວ 26:9}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ອວຍພອນ ພວກເຂົາ ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ກ່າວ ຕໍ່ ພວກເຂົາ ວ່າ, “ຈົ່ງ ມີ ລູກ ດົກ ແລະ ທະວີ ຫຼາຍ ຂຶ້ນ ແລະ ເຕັມ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ, ຈົ່ງ ມີ ອຳນາດ ເໜືອ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ນັ້ນ ແລະ ຄອບຄອງ ເໜືອ ປາ ໃນ ທະເລ ແລະ ເໜືອ ສັດປີກ ໃນ ອາກາດ ແລະ ເໜືອ ທຸກໆ ສິ່ງ ທີ່ ມີຊີວິດ ທີ່ ເຄື່ອນໄຫວ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ.”
\vs{29}
\crossref{ປຖກ 9:3; ພສສ 104:14-15}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ຈົ່ງເບິ່ງ, ເຮົາ ໄດ້ ໃຫ້ ເຈົ້າ ບັນດາ ພືດຜັກ ທີ່ ເກີດ ເມັດພັນ ເຊິ່ງ ຢູ່ ທົ່ວ ເທິງ ພື້ນ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ແລະ ບັນດາ ຕົ້ນໄມ້ ເຊິ່ງ ມີ ຜົນ ຂອງ ຕົ້ນໄມ້ ທີ່ ໃຫ້ ເມັດພັນ; ມັນ ຈະ ເປັນ ອາຫານ ສຳລັບ ເຈົ້າ.
\vs{30}
\crossref{ພສສ 145:15; ໂຢບ 38:41}
ແລະ ສຳລັບ ບັນດາ ສັດ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ, ແລະ ບັນດາ ສັດປີກ ໃນ ອາກາດ ແລະ ທຸກໆ ສິ່ງ ທີ່ ເລືອຄານ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ທີ່ ມີ ຊີວິດ, ເຮົາ ໄດ້ ໃຫ້ ບັນດາ ພືດຜັກ ສີຂຽວ ເປັນ ອາຫານ”: ແລະ ເປັນ ດັ່ງນັ້ນ.
\vs{31}
\crossref{ພສສ 104:24}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເຫັນ ທຸກໆ ສິ່ງ ທີ່ ພຣະອົງ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ສ້າງ, ແລະ ຈົ່ງເບິ່ງ, ເປັນ ສິ່ງ ທີ່ ດີ ຫຼາຍ: ຕອນແລງ ແລະ ຕອນເຊົ້າ ເປັນ ມື້ ທີ ຫົກ.

\hspace{0pt} 
\endgroup

\begingroup
\begin{minipage}{.25in}{\hspace{20pt}\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont \textbf{\ch{2}} \par}\end{minipage}\markboth{ປະຖົມມະການ 2}{ປະຖົມມະການ 2}\crossref{ພສສ 33:6}
ດັ່ງນັ້ນ ຟ້າສະຫວັນ ແລະ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ໄດ້ ສຳເລັດ ແລະ ບັນດາ ສັບພະສິ່ງ ທັງໝົດ.
\vs{2}
\crossref{ອພຍ 20:11; ຮຣ 4:4}
ແລະ ໃນ ມື້ ທີ ເຈັດ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ກໍ ສຳເລັດ ວຽກງານ ຂອງ ພຣະອົງ ເຊິ່ງ ພຣະອົງ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ສ້າງ; ແລະ ພຣະອົງ ຊົງ ພັກຜ່ອນ ໃນ ມື້ ທີ ເຈັດ ຈາກ ການງານ ທັງໝົດ ຂອງ ພຣະອົງ ເຊິ່ງ ພຣະອົງ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ສ້າງ.
\vs{3}
\crossref{ອຊຢ 58:13}
ແລະ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ອວຍພຣະພອນ ມື້ ທີ ເຈັດ ແລະ ເຮັດ ໃຫ້ ສັກສິດ, ເພາະ ໃນ ມື້ ນັ້ນ ພຣະອົງ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ພັກຜ່ອນ ຈາກ ການງານ ທັງໝົດ ຂອງ ພຣະອົງ ເຊິ່ງ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ນິລະມິດ ສ້າງ ແລະ ຊົງ ເຮັດ.
\vs{4}
\crossref{ປຖກ 1:1}
ນີ້ ແມ່ນ ເຊື້ອສາຍ ຂອງ ຟ້າສະຫວັນ ແລະ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ເມື່ອ ຖືກ ນິລະມິດ ສ້າງ, ໃນ ມື້ ທີ່ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ສ້າງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ແລະ ຟ້າສະຫວັນ.
\vs{5}
\crossref{ປຖກ 1:12; ໂຢບ 38:26-28; ປຖກ 3:23}
ແລະ ບັນດາ ຕົ້ນໄມ້ ຕາມ ທົ່ງ ຍັງ ບໍ່ ເກີດຂຶ້ນ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ແລະ ບັນດາ ພືດຜັກ ຕາມ ທົ່ງ ຍັງ ບໍ່ ງອກ ຂຶ້ນ ເລີຍ, ເພາະ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຍັງ ບໍ່ ໃຫ້ ຝົນຕົກ ເທິງ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ ແລະ ຍັງ ບໍ່ ມີ ມະນຸດ ທີ່ ຈະ ເຮັດໄຮ່ໄຖນາ.
\vs{6}
ແຕ່ ມີ ໝອກ ຂຶ້ນມາ ຈາກ ແຜ່ນດິນໂລກ, ເຮັດໃຫ້ ພື້ນ ແຜ່ນດິນ ປຽກຊຸ່ມ ທົ່ວໄປ.
\vs{7}
\crossref{ປຖກ 3:19,23; ພສສ 103:14; ໂຢບ 33:4; ປຖກ 7:22; 1 ກຣທ 15:45}
ແລະ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ປັ້ນ ມະນຸດ ດ້ວຍ ຝຸ່ນດິນ ແລະ ຊົງ ລະບາຍ ລົມຫາຍໃຈ ແຫ່ງ ຊີວິດ ເຂົ້າ ທາງ ດັງ ຂອງ ເຂົາ ແລະ ມະນຸດ ຈຶ່ງ ກາຍເປັນ ຜູ້ ເປັນ ຊີວິດ ຈິດວິນຍານ.
\vs{8}
\crossref{ອຊຢ 51:3; ປຖກ 3:24; ປຖກ 4:16}
ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ປູກ ສວນ ທາງ ທິດ ຕາເວັນອອກ ໃນ ເອເດັນ ແລະ ພຣະອົງ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ໃສ່ ມະນຸດ ເຊິ່ງ ພຣະອົງ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ປັ້ນ ມາ ໄວ້ ທີ່ນັ້ນ.
\vs{9}
\crossref{ອຊກ 31:8; ປຖກ 3:22; ພນມ 2:7}
ແລະ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເຮັດໃຫ້ ອອກຈາກ ແຜ່ນດິນ ບັນດາ ຕົ້ນໄມ້ ເຕີບໃຫຍ່ ເຊິ່ງ ງາມ ຕໍ່ ສາຍຕາ ແລະ ດີ ສຳລັບ ອາຫານ;  ຕົ້ນໄມ້ ແຫ່ງ ຊີວິດ ກໍ ຢູ່ ໃນ ທ່າມກາງ ສວນ ແລະ ຕົ້ນໄມ້ ແຫ່ງ ຄວາມຮູ້ ດີ ແລະ ຊົ່ວ.
\vs{10}
ມີ ແມ່ນໍ້າ ສາຍ ໜຶ່ງ ໄຫຼ ອອກຈາກ ເອເດັນ ຮົດ ສວນ ນັ້ນ; ແລະ ຈາກ ບ່ອນນັ້ນ ໄດ້ ແຍກ ອອກ ເປັນ ແມ່ນໍ້າ ສີ່ ສາຍ.
\vs{11}
\crossref{ປຖກ 25:18}
ຊື່ ຂອງ ແມ່ນໍ້າ ສາຍ ທີ ໜຶ່ງ ຄື ປິໂຊນ ເຊິ່ງ ໄຫຼ ຮອບ ແຜ່ນດິນ ຮາວິລາ; ບ່ອນນັ້ນ ມີ ແຮ່ ທອງຄຳ.
\vs{12}
\crossref{ຈບຊ 11:7}
ແລະ ທອງຄຳ ທີ່ ແຜ່ນດິນ ນັ້ນ ເປັນ ເນື້ອດີ: ມີ ຢາງໄມ້ຫອມ ແລະ ພອຍສີນໍ້າມວກ.
\vs{13}
ແລະ ຊື່ ແມ່ນໍ້າ ສາຍ ທີ ສອງ ຄື ກິໂຮນ:  ແມ່ນໍ້າ ສາຍ ນີ້ ໄດ້ ໄຫຼ ອ້ອມ ແຜ່ນດິນ ເອທິໂອເປຍ.
\vs{14}
\crossref{ດນອ 10:4}
ແລະ ຊື່ ແມ່ນໍ້າ ສາຍ ທີ ສາມ ຄື ໄທກຣິສ, ເຊິ່ງ ໄດ້ ໄຫຼ ໄປ ທາງ ທິດ ຕາເວັນອອກ ຂອງ ແຜ່ນດິນ ອັດຊີເຣຍ; ແລະ ແມ່ນໍ້າ ສາຍ ທີ ສີ່ ຄື ເອີ​ຟ​ຣັດ.
\vs{15}
ແລະ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຈຶ່ງ ຊົງ ນຳ ມະນຸດ ໄປ ຢູ່ ໃນ ສວນ ເອເດັນ ໃຫ້ ເບິ່ງແຍງ ແລະ ຮັກສາ ສວນ.
\vs{16}
ແລະ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ສັ່ງ ມະນຸດ ວ່າ, “ຈາກ ບັນດາ ຕົ້ນໄມ້ ໃນ ສວນ ເຈົ້າ ກິນ ໄດ້;
\vs{17}
\crossref{ປຖກ 3:1,3,11,17,19; ຣມ 6:23}
ແຕ່ ຕົ້ນໄມ້ ແຫ່ງ ຄວາມຮູ້ ດີ ແລະ ຮູ້ ຊົ່ວ ເຈົ້າ ຢ່າ ກິນ ຈາກ ຕົ້ນ ນັ້ນ ເພາະວ່າ ໃນ ມື້ ທີ່ ເຈົ້າ ກິນ ຈາກ ຕົ້ນ ນັ້ນ ເຈົ້າ ຈະ ຕາຍ ແນ່ນອນ.”
\vs{18}
\crossref{1 ກຣທ 11:9; 1 ຕມທ 2:13}
ແລະ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ບໍ່ ເໝາະສົມ ທີ່ ມະນຸດ ນັ້ນ ຢູ່ ຄົນ ດຽວ; ເຮົາ ຈະ ສ້າງ ຜູ້ອຸປະຖຳ ເໝາະສົມ ສຳລັບ ລາວ.”
\vs{19}
\crossref{ປຖກ 1:20,24; ພສສ 8:6}
ແລະ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ປັ້ນ ຈາກ ດິນ ບັນດາ ສັດ ໃນ ທົ່ງ ແລະ ບັນດາ ສັດປີກ ໃນ ອາກາດ; ແລະ ຈຶ່ງ ພາ ມາ ຍັງ ອາດາມ ເພື່ອ ເບິ່ງ ວ່າ ລາວ ຈະ ເອີ້ນ ຊື່ ພວກ ມັນ ວ່າ ຢ່າງໃດ; ແລະ ຊື່ ໃດ ທີ່ ອາດາມ ໄດ້ ເອີ້ນ ບັນດາ ສັດ ທີ່ ມີ ຊີວິດ, ສັດ ກໍ ມີ ຊື່ ຢ່າງນັ້ນ.
\vs{20}
ອາດາມ ໄດ້ ຕັ້ງ ຊື່ ບັນດາ ສັດໃຊ້ແຮງງານ, ບັນດາ ສັດປີກ ໃນ ອາກາດ, ແລະ ບັນດາ ສັດ ໃນ ທົ່ງ; ແຕ່ວ່າ ສຳລັບ ອາດາມ ຍັງ ບໍ່ ພົບ ຜູ້ອຸປະຖຳ ເໝາະສົມ ສຳລັບ ລາວ.
\vs{21}
\crossref{1 ຊມອ 26:12}
ແລະ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ຊົງ ເຮັດ ໃຫ້ ການ ຫຼັບ ສະໜິດ ຕົກ ເທິງ ອາດາມ, ແລະ ລາວ ໄດ້ ຫຼັບ: ແລະ ພຣະອົງ ເອົາ ກະດູກຂ້າງ ອັນ ໜຶ່ງ ຂອງ ລາວ ອອກ ແລະ ຊົງ ເຮັດ ໃຫ້ ເນື້ອໜັງ ຕິດ ກັນ ໃນ ທີ່ ນັ້ນ.
\vs{22}
\crossref{ຮຣ 13:4}
ແລະ ກະດູກຂ້າງ, ເຊິ່ງ ພຣະເຢໂຮວາ ພຣະເຈົ້າ ໄດ້ ຊົງ ເອົາ ຈາກ ຊາຍ ນັ້ນ, ພຣະອົງ ຊົງ ສ້າງ ໃຫ້ ເປັນ ຍິງ ຄົນ ໜຶ່ງ ແລະ ຊົງ ນຳ ນາງ ມາ ໃຫ້ ຊາຍ ນັ້ນ.
\vs{23}
\crossref{ປຖກ 29:14; ອຟຊ 5:30; 1 ກຣທ 11:8}
ແລະ ອາດາມ ກ່າວ ວ່າ, “ບັດນີ້ ນີ້ ເປັນ ກະດູກ ຈາກ ກະດູກ ຂອງ ເຮົາ ແລະ ເນື້ອໜັງ ຈາກ ເນື້ອໜັງ ຂອງ ເຮົາ, ນາງ ຈະ ຖືກ ເອີ້ນ ວ່າ “ຍິງ” ເພາະວ່າ ນາງ ໄດ້ ຖືກ ອອກມາ ຈາກ ຊາຍ.
\vs{24}
\crossref{ມທ 19:5; ອຟຊ 5:31}
ເຫດສະນັ້ນ ຜູ້ຊາຍ ຈະ ຈາກ ພໍ່ແມ່ ຂອງ ລາວ, ຈະ ໄປ ຜູກພັນ ຢູ່ ກັບ ເມຍ ແລະ ພວກເຂົາ ຈະ ເປັນ ເນື້ອໜັງ ອັນ ດຽວກັນ.”
\vs{25}
\crossref{ປຖກ 3:7,10; ອຊຢ 47:3}
ເຂົາ ທັງສອງ ເປືອຍກາຍ ຢູ່, ຜູ້ຊາຍ ແລະ ເມຍ ຂອງ ລາວ, ແລະ ບໍ່ ມີ ອັບອາຍ.

\hspace{0pt} 
\endgroup

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Apparently, based on an earlier question ["Thin spaces converted to regular width space in PDF output"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526713/thin-spaces-converted-to-regular-width-space-in-pdf-output), some packages (e.g. polyglossia) use the thin space for spacing French punctuation characters properly, in a context where word-wrapping would not be permissible.  However, I am neither using polyglossia, nor working with French, and yet not even the zero-width space (ZWSP) characters--widely used expressly for word-boundary definitions in cases like this--are treated as expected.

Do I have some package conflict?  Why does TeX not treat these characters properly?

[NOTE: The mis-alignment of the chapter numbers is a separate, unrelated issue which I'm still working on.]

Comment: `\newunicodechar{^^^^200b}{^^^^200b\allowbreak}` will do the trick (requires the `newunicodechar` package).